# Best Practice using async await for setState in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm new in React Native. But i'm aware if this.setState method is run in asynchronous mode.

I have a snippet code like this :

```
async doSave() {
        await this.props.takeCustomerServiceTicket(this.state.name, this.state.address, this.state.password);
        await this.setState({
            name: '',
            address: '',
            password: ''
        });
    };
```

What i want to ask are :

1. Is setState can be await like that? the code not show error, but it really effective to make it await ?
2. Is my code really synchronous after i use async await like that?
3. I'm afraid about by reference, are name, address, password that passed via takeCustomerServiceTicket still exist until the function finish ? or it loss because my setState ?

Comment: `async` and `await` is only syntax sugar, it doesn't magically make asynchronous operations synchronous (which is usually impossible)

Comment: @CertainPerformance : but is it secure do like my code ?

Comment: There are no security risks in the code you posted, but `await this.setState` still just doesn't make any sense

Comment: Oh ic. is it possible setState running first before takeCustomerServiceTicket ? If yes, i afraid the value loss before using by takeCustomerServiceTicket

Comment: Shouldn't be an issue, the primitive is effectively copied when the function is called (make sure `takeCustomerServiceTicket` returns a `Promise`)

Comment: name is a String. the text/string not a primitive data type right?

Comment: No, strings are primitives